# Zend search Lucene php - Manage synonyms

Tags: zend-framework, synonym, zend-search-lucene

I use zend search lucene to create a search engine for a website. I want to let the user use synonyms for his request.
For exemple, if he search "jeans", he should be able to find things about "jeans" and "pants".

Is there anything in zend lucene that may help me or do i have to do it with php (i mean, do i have to add synonyms by myself ?) ?

Comment: This sounds like a question about _avoiding_ programming, rather than programming.

Comment: Reinvent the wheel is not always a good idea

Comment: My point is that if it's about avoiding programming, this isn't the site for it. See [On Topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more info.